# What is the basis on which expats are allowed to vote in their home countries?

Tags: voting, democracy, expat

Despite being an expat (having a long-term permanent residence in a another country and not paying any taxes or similar obligations back in my country of citizenship), I still have the right to vote in national assembly and presidental elections. The government goes to great length to enable that - establishing a process for remote elections, sending out ballots ahead of time, delaying result counts until all ballots arrive and opening voting spaces in consulates and embassies around the world.

According to Wikipedia, 93 of world countries allow their expats to vote (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_of_expatriates_to_vote_in_their_country_of_origin).

My question here is: why? What is the legal or moral rationale for governments and countries to go out of their way to enable the voting right of the people which are not connected to the life in the country on day-to-day basis and don't have a big stake in outcome in any case? One could argue, that expats are significantly more interested in governmental elections in their new country of residence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question but also fairly hard to answer entirely conclusively - i.e. your points against are fairly solid.

- A nationality's primary benefit/distinguishing characteristic  is the right to vote in many ways.  In well-run, democratic, countries, as a foreign resident you get almost all the rights citizens get, *except the right to vote*.  Conversely, having non-voting citizens is almost a contradiction in terms.  So stripping it away on the basis of location would just be *harsh* and would make a mockery of being a citizen.  So you'd have a massive legal technicality problem:  how to keep someone a citizen, but not allow them to vote?
- Many countries benefit greatly from their diaspora and cultivate it by having outreach programs in their consulates.  Expats can influence their host country's opinion positively - witness the impact the Ukrainian diaspora has had on the war (while the Russian diaspora generally opposes said war).  They can send remittances which in many countries is a significant source of income, the Philippines for example.
- An expat is often just temporarily so and a country may not want to burn its bridges with their citizens and completely dissuade them from coming back.  In many cases, such as China, returnees bring back very useful technical and organizational skills.
- Any party suddenly proposing such a change in a competitive free election would first push the expats to vote against them and second motivate many of their acquaintances to take that position into account when voting.
- The "gains" would be meager as well - what exactly would the home country gain from doing this?  Some notion of fairness in only allowing people who have "skin in the game"?  Sure, but that's a vague gain, against fairly concrete losses.

Expat French myself, living in Canada where I hold Canadian citizenship as well, *usually* prefer to sit out elections because of just your reasons:  "not my business to tell them how to live".

I did vote in the last 2 elections, mostly because of the nature of the alternatives, but there is a lot to be said about lacking a strong feeling that I am entitled to vote in a country I no longer reside in, nor have any intent to go back to.

p.s. dual nationalities aside, in most places expats would not be able to take part in local elections, whether or not they'd want to, so that's not really a factor.